# i'm writing a cpp program to print all prime numbers between two numbers . Program is running successfully but it is not printing anything

Tags: c++, namespaces, primes, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num){
    for(int i=2;i<=num;i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            cout<<i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me my mistake, program is running successfully but not printing anything.

Comment: I recommend that you take this as an opportunity to learn how to *debug* your programs. More specifically how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: *"program is running successfully but not printing anything."* -- This tells me that the program is supposed to not print anything. Because if it was supposed to print something, then it is **not** running successfully. It might be running without error messages, but that is not the same as being successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for(int i=2;i<num;i++)

you've used i<=num where the logic should be i<num in your isPrime function. cause all the primes are divided by themselves. but you should not count that while finding primes

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're checking all divisors from `2` to `num`, inclusive.  Since every positive integer divides itself, you're not finding any primes.  The minimal fix is to change the loop exit condition to exclude `num`:

```
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
```

Note that this will work, but it's very inefficient.  Here's a much faster version.  This version also rejects anything less than 2, since 0 and 1 aren't prime:

```
bool isPrime(int num){
    if (num < 2){
        return false;
    }
    if (num == 2){
        return true;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0){
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=3; i*i<=num; i+=2){
        if(num%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This version makes a special case check for `2`, and for even numbers.  After that, it only checks for odd divisors.  Once the divisor exceeds sqrt(num), it can stop (the loop exits when `i*i > num`).